# How do I prevent IntelliJ from copying resources into the project compiler output directory?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I have the following directory structure within IntelliJ, which contains an Android library project:

```
java/com/example/base/AndroidManifest.xml
java/com/example/base/assets # contains Android assets
java/com/example/base/res    # contains Android resources
java/com/example/base/Base.java
java/com/example/base/base.iml
```

The `base.iml` contains the following:

```
<content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$"
                isTestSource="false"
                packagePrefix="com.example.base" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/gen" isTestSource="false" />
  <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/res" />
</content>
```

When I build an Android application project that depends on my library project, I get an error:

```
[myapp] java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: res/drawable/image_shadow.9.png
```

In the **Project Structure** dialog, I configured **Project compiler output** to be an `out` directory under the root of my project. When I try to build my Android project, I noticed that copies of my Android resources end up under the `out/production/base/com/example/base/res/` folder.

My hypothesis is that my Android resources are being treated like "normal" Java resources (the type you would load using `Class.getResource()`), which is why they are being copied to `out/production`, which in turn causes the `duplicate entry` exception that I am seeing.

Any idea if this is the case? If so, how can I prevent these files from being copied over? In Eclipse, the `<classpathentry>` element in the `.classpath` file has an `excluding` attribute that takes a glob pattern to prevent this sort of behavior.

Comment: I should add that I tried the `<excludeFolder>` thing as a shot in the dark. Any solution that requires it is somewhat undesirable because that hides my `res` folder from the source tree in IntelliJ's UI. I want to exclude the folder from being considered for compilation, not from being visible.

Comment: The problem might be in your Android facet settings, probably the wrong directory is configured there as `res`. Can't say more without your `.iml` files.

Comment: I believe that my facet has the standard boilerplate:

    <component name="FacetManager">
      <facet type="android" name="Android">
        <configuration>
          <option name="RES_FOLDER_RELATIVE_PATH" value="/res" />
        </configuration>
      </facet>
    </component>

SO doesn't seem to let me paste the entire thing.

I'm curious whether this interaction with packagePrefix and Android library projects has been tested before?

Comment: @CrazyCoder Here is a minimalist example that identifies the bug: https://github.com/bolinfest/intellij-android-resource-bug I believe this is a bug in IntelliJ -- is there a workaround?

Comment: Normally `AndroidManifest.xml` (and `res`, and other folders) resides outside of the source root, in your project the root of the module is configured as source, so this file is processed according to `Settings` | `Compiler` | `Resource Patterns`. As a workaround you can [add it to the compiler excludes](http://img834.imageshack.us/img834/6752/20121023042449.png) (same for other files and directories that you don't want to be processed this way).

Comment: This does not answer the detailed question, but when running script based tools that don't require compilation (eg. Ruby), removing the 'make' step from 'before launch' on the 'run/debug configuration' will stop resources being copied.   Putting this here in case people follow the question title but for contexts where compilation is not required.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar problem because the `main` dir was marked as "Sources".

So in project structure, for the Android facet, under the "Structure" tab I had:

`...
Resources directory: .../src/main/res
...`

And under the normal "Sources" tab for the module, the `main` dir under `src` had been marked as "Sources".

I fixed it by making the Sources tab look like:

`- src      (unmarked)
  - main   (unmarked)
    - java (Sources)
    - res  (Resources)`

So I guess the error is because the res things are being packed into the zip both as sources and resources hence the duplication.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a project structure like:

- project/src/main/res
- project/src/main/assets
- project/src/main/java
- project/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Anyway, for res folder you should have an entry like this:

```
    <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/res" type="java-resource" />
```